# Как ограничить частоту отправок данных из формы на ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Конкретно в этой форме, например 1 отправка в 30 минут.
Спасибо!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //E-mail Ajax Send
        $("form").submit(function() {
            var th = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php",
                data: th.serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                alert("Спасибо! Мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Done Functions
                    th.trigger("reset");
                }, 1000);
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
```

Comment: Вообще правильнее всего это делать на стороне backend, так как любые ограничения на frontend легко обходяться. Но если приципиально чтобы это было на фронтенд, сейчас напишу решение.

Comment: Я пока вообще не силен в каких-либо разработках, изучаю, поэтому мне что нибудь из "простого")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При отправке можно записывать время последней отправленой формы, после чего при следующей проверке проверять прошло 30 минут или нет.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//E-mail Ajax Send
$("form").submit(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('lastSend') && new Date().getTime() - localStorage.getItem('lastSend') < 30 * 60 * 1000){
        return false;
    }
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function () {
        alert("Спасибо! Мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.");
        localStorage.setItem('lastSend', new Date().getTime());
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Done Functions
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```